# sails js recommended database for realtime e-commerce and inventory application

Tags: mysql, mongodb, e-commerce, sails.js, rethinkdb

What is the recommended database for realtime e-commerce and inventory application in sails js framework? much preferred a nosql but is there any?

Update:
Mongodb has use cases for inventory and ecommerce: http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/use-cases/inventory-management/

sails js can combine mysql and mongodb for making transactions ACID

How about rethinkdb?

So mysql, mongodb, mysql and mongodb, or rethinkdb?

Answer (score 1):

At present, there's no official RethinkDB adapter for Sails.js. For SQL, look into using http://www.postgresql.org/. For noSQL, stick with MongoDB. You can use a combination of both. Also, you can get realtime with the integrated Socket.io.

Answer (score 0):

PostgreSQL good for your case, pgSQL can save object json for NoSQL approach but very limitation for NoSQL. but i recommend you to combine postgreSQL with rethinkDB , for adapter you can use adapter [waterline-rethinkDB](https://github.com/jmdobry/waterline-rethinkdb) because sailsJS use waterline in their ORM.
hopefully can help you.